# useEffect is not working in functional component,showing null data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

UseEffecct is not getting the data from the API,it is showing null when I try to console........................................

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function footerAjax() {
     const [data, setData1] = useState('');
     useEffect(async () => {
       
            console.log("inerrrr");
            axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("api --"+JSON.stringify(res.data));
                setData1(res.data);
            });
       
    },[]);

    return (
        <div className="app">
            
            {console.log("footer == "+JSON.stringify(data??{}))}
            <FooterBody footerData={data??{}} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That’s unfortunate. It wouldn’t show anything for at least 20 seconds; there’s no way for us to know why it might not show anything after that. If nothing else you may have wanted an empty dependency list for the effect hook, though.

Comment: `get('api()')` - That sure doesn't look like a URL.  Are there any errors at all on the browser's developer console?  What debugging have you done?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Which console log exactly is showing `null`? You have a lot of them

Comment: console.log("inerrrr");          console.log("api --"+JSON.stringify(res.data));    are not working

Comment: How are you using `footerAjax`? Normally components should start with a capital letter. The capital letter signals JSX that we're working with a custom component. If you are using `<footerAjax />` then your component is never invoked. Use `<FooterAjax />` instead. See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Answer (score 0):

I can see multiple issues in the code snippet :

1. Where is the dependencies array for the `useEffect` hook ?
2. Why adding the `async` keyword in both `useEffect` and `setTimeout` ?
3. In this line : `console.log("footer == "+JSON.stringify(data??{}))`
   I guess you meant : `console.log("footer == ",JSON.stringify(data??{}))`
   (same for the previous console.log)
4. Avoid using `setTimeout` if you don't need it
5. Import `axios`

Try correcting these issues then build again.

Answer (score 0):

In your api does returns only array of objects. so it doesnot have key called data its becoming undefined. just remove ***data*** key it should work.

```
console.log("api --"+JSON.stringify(res));
setData1(res);
```

hope this helps!!